# Creating a Joomla 1.7 Content Plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6, joomla1.7

I'm trying to create a Joomla 1.7 content plugin that, ultimately, will send an email when a brand new article has been created on the backend. My plugin, while it installed correctly, doesn't seem to be firing properly. I modified by plugin so that it should, on the creation of a new article, cancel the save event and display an error message instead. This isn't happening, and articles are being saved just fine. Am I missing something obvious here? I even tried adding a `die()` and `mail()` command inside the `onBeforeContentSave()` method and it never got executed.

**notifyy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="1.7" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>Content - Notifyy</name>
    <author>Andy Soell</author>
    <creationDate>August 1, 2011</creationDate>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <authorEmail>my@email.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://andy.teamsoell.com</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Notification for new articles</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="notifyy">notifyy.php</filename>
    </files>    
</extension>
```

**notifyy.php**

```
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

class plgContentNotifyy extends JPlugin {

    function plgContentNotifyy( &$subject, $params )
    {
        parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
    }

    function onBeforeContentSave( &$article, $isNew )
    {
        global $mainframe;

        $article->setError("i don't want to save this");
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel silly, but Joomla's site really needs to document their changes between versions a little better. It appears that the method names have changed from version 1.5 to 1.6, and their documentation still indicates the 1.5 names. The `onBeforeContentSave()` method is now to be referenced as `onContentBeforeSave()`.

Further details found at: http://www.theartofjoomla.com/converting-old-extensions.html

Comment: Did you document your findings on the Joomla wiki? Joomla is a community project. The problem is that too many developers complain about the lack of documentation without doing anything about it :)

Answer (score 2):

The joomla developer docs do contain info on renamed events.

See: http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Renamed_events